# hide an element if span element contains div with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, angularjs

I have an issue,
I am trying to hide an "i" element if a "span" contains a "div" element. 
the "span" contains text loaded via AJAX rendered as HTML
that may or may not contain the "div class=difference"

the code looks something like this:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$scope.hasChild = function() {
    if ($('span.difference').has('div'))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
};
```

HTML:

```
<ul ng-repeat="instance in value">
    <li>
        <i class="fa fa-warning" style="color: #ff6a00;" ng-if="hasChild()"></i>
        <span class="difference" ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(instance.Dati)"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

it keeps always showing the warning icon

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide minimal complete sample what you have?

Comment: These are actually two questions. 1. Wait until the included `view` is completely rendered 2. Then hide the element based on condition

Comment: A fiddle link will be helpfull..

Comment: can you provide how do ajax request?

Comment: Nesting `<div>` elements inside `<span>` elements is asking for trouble in the first place -- inline elements cannot contain block elements.

Comment: the data are retrieved from a database...i think i can't give you anything more than what i've already written that would be of any help. If u have any suggestion please tell me!!!

Comment: ok fredric...it's no problem for me changing the way data are recieved, i can easly switch to a span, so the situation will be a span inside a span

Comment: @Alex0494 can you provide code for your ajax request and sample response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since jQuery's `.has()` always returns an object, even if your span is empty, the condition is always true. 
Try something like

```
$scope.hasChild = function() {
    return $('span.difference').find('div').length > 0;
};
```

But this will search in all `span`s with class `difference`. Try checking the instances `Dati` property instead.

```
<i class="fa fa-warning" style="color: #ff6a00;" ng-if="hasChild(instance.Dati)"></i>

$scope.hasChild = function(dati) {
    var dummy = document.createElement("div"); //create a dummy element
    dummy.innerHTML = dati;
    return $(dummy).find("> div").length > 0; //check if it has divs inside
};
```

BTW.: [You should not put a block element inside an inline element.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)

Comment: if i not mistaken - `this` in this case referse to `scope`

Comment: methinks if you do `createElement` without jQuery so possibly and check div can be something like `dummy.querySelector('div') != null`

Comment: yeah man it worked like charm ;) thank you it was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You're using a global selector here (`span.difference`):

```
$scope.hasChild = function() {
    if ($('span.difference').has('div'))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
};
```

So the condition for all the element would be based on the first (or maybe last?) span element.

Anyway, you need to modify your `hasChild` function only for the span sibling of the current element. Something like:

```
if ($(this).siblings('span.difference').find('div').length > 0)
```

---

Here's a jQuery-only version, should be easy to rewrite into Angular (let me know if you need help with that):

```js
$('i').each(function() {
  if ($(this).siblings('span.difference').find('div').length > 0)
    $(this).show();
  else
    $(this).hide();
})
```

```css
i {background: #ff6a00;}
div {padding-bottom: 20px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <i class="fa fa-warning">Warning</i>
  <span class="difference">Span 1</span>
</div>
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-warning">Warning</i>
  <span class="difference">Span 2<div>with a div (not a proper structure btw)</div></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this??

```
if ($('span.difference').html().match("(<div\b)(.*)(>)")!=null)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Comment: That's risky - what if the span contains a word "diversity", for example?

Comment: Haha, yeah, that's why regex is usually bad for DOM.

Comment: ahaha i want a solution with regex u.u

Comment: Haha, once (and if) you manage to set all the exceptions, you'll end up with a regex the size of the rest of the code :)

Comment: Ummm, `<div></div>`? :D

Comment: not working, the condition is never verified...maybe it's because of the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

"ng-if" accepts expressions.
Please refer here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

For your case, you just need to update the function to below.

```
$scope.isDanger = false;
$scope.hasChild = function() {
    if ($('span.difference').has('div').find('div').length > 0)
        $scope.isDanger = true;
    else
        $scope.isDanger = false;
};
```

And Forgot to mention, you need to call the $scope.hasChild() function after ajax response.
And replace  tag with below

```
<i class="fa fa-warning" style="color: #ff6a00;" ng-if="isDanger"></i>
```

Comment: what the difference with OP variant?

Comment: And what will call the `hasChild` function for each element? How would multiple elements be handled?

Comment: @Grundy, the difference is that this won't work **at all** :D

Comment: Please view the above reply now, Corrected And Edited. Sorry for the inconvenience caused. ;)

Comment: It still needs to work for multiple elements individually. This will use a single value for all of them.